# Can 22.5 amps , 10000 turn coil achive 1 Tesla?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic

Can an electromagnets with 10000 turns and 22.5 amp current get 1 Tesla?
Diameter of coil = 0.5 cm
Length of wire =314m

Real question: how do I build a rTMS.

rTMS:- repetitive transcranial magnetic stimulation.

Comment: What answer did you get when you plugged it into the formula that you didn't include in your question?

Comment: based off your question, any coil can get 1 T, as the length -> 0

Comment: Please who is your intended test subject? This project seems like an accident waiting to happen. And I dont see you managing to get 22.5A through that magnet, and 1T, - speaking seriously you would be better designing the magnet and selecting the correct power supply for the application rather than suggesting a spec for a magnet and asking if it will do what you want to achieve - and do you REALLY want to put guesswork into blasting your brain?.

Comment: And 1T at what distance? Over what area?

Comment: Need to know wire size and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given before the OP modified the question and stated that the real question was to build a rTMS (whatever that is).

See this diagram: -

[image]

For one wire at a distance of 1 mm from a wire conducting 22.5 amps, the flux density is 0.0045 T. When close to that conducting wire you can assume all the flux comes from that wire (and not the return wire) for the sake of simplicity.

If there are ten wires wound so that they are all about 1mm from a single point, the flux density is going to be about 0.045 T. Remember, I'm just putting some numbers on the formula to give you a feel - you'll need to do the math on the whole coil.

So, taking this a little further, if there is a 2nd layer of wires above the first layer that is also conducting the same current but maybe 0.5mm further away, the contribution from that 2nd layer is going to be 0.03 T.

Net contribution from both layers is 0.075 T.

All you need to do next is follow my lead and using the knowledge you have about the shape of the coil and the number of layers and the coil spacings, work out whether you can reach 1 T.

Or you can go to [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html) and put the numbers in on this page: -

[image]

I've done the first calculation for you and get a flux density at the centre of a 5mm diameter single turn coil to be 0.057 T. You can even add an offset on the z-axis to account for coild that are a bit further away. I reckon you could have your answer in about an hour to a reasonable degree of certainty.

Not sure how long you very thin piece of copper wire is going to survive at 22.5 amps though. Are you planning on cooling it?

Comment: You should check out his/her first question, I believe you'll get the big picture.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I have the bigger picture now!

Comment: Interesting application which I thought was called iFMS for intracranial functional magnetic stimulation and just FMS for the rest of the body to excite Action Potential of the axon cells for self-healing possibilities.  It seems EU is 4 or 5 yrs ahead of ROTW here.